# python regex with duplicated string

Tags: python, regex

I have a question about python regex. 
I am trying to get count of the number start with 1, end with 1, and between 1s there are only 0s from the string.

The problem is if the number is 10101, it should return 2, but based on my regex, it returns 1.

```
[(1)][(0)]+[(1)]
```

How can I change this regex to count duplicated 1 between two 101s?

https://regex101.com/r/R78CRD/1/

Comment: *if the number is 10101, it should return 2...* what do you mean exactly?

Comment: @revo Thanks for your reply. It means there are two 101 in that string. First three numbers and last three numbers.

Comment: In your comment, you are talking about digits, not numbers. Use proper terminology, and people would know what you mean.

Comment: 2 notes: 1) `[(1)]` means a character class containing `1`,`(` and `)` individually. So it matches all three characters. You don't need a character class at all. `1` is enough. 2) You should use a positive lookahead `10+(?=1)` to make a right assertion otherwise a match will happen which engine won't retry matching over it again.

Comment: Why is this question asked several times today for different languages? The third one already.

Answer (score 3):

Regex only counts non-overlapping matches. Your regex however matches two `1`s, so regex skips forward to the 3rd `1` and continues to count from there.

You can use a [lookahead assertion](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#lookahead-assertions) to fix this:

```
10+(?=1)
```